# groupBy with 3 ConstraintCollectors?

Tags: optaplanner

I like to schedule observations of variable duration (planning entity) into hourly time slots over several nights. I would need to impose that there are no gaps in particular groups, and need collectors for minimum, maximum and sum. Is there a workaround to have a `groupBy` with one groupKeyMapping and ***three*** collectors?

```
constraintFactory.from(OB.class)
    .groupBy(OB::getGroupID, min(OB::getStart), max(OB::getEnd), sum(OB::getDuration))
```

I tried to workaround this using `toList()` and computing values myself but strangely it doesn't pass down a `List<OB>` but single `OB`s. The code below prints `class my.package.OB`

```
constraintFactory.from(OB.class)
   .groupBy(OB::getGroupID, toList())
   .filter((groupID, entries) -> {
       println "=> ${entries.class} "
       return true
   })
```

Comment: Looks like **an API gap**.

Comment: The part where it does not pass down a list is a bug that has been fixed for OptaPlanner 8.2.0. The main question is, indeed, an API gap.

Comment: Thank you. I can confirm that `toList()` now works with the 8.2.0 snapshot. Would be nice to have the API gap addressed.

Answer (score 0):

This was a gap in our API ([see PLANNER-2330](https://issues.redhat.com/browse/PLANNER-2330)). It is being addressed for OptaPlanner 8.3.0. We encourage you to upgrade - not only to get this particular feature, but also some nice performance improvements, assuming you're using higher cardinality joins.